# Runtime function + boost::bind c++

Tags: c++, function, boost, runtime

assuming that a function f uses template parameters, how could I at runtime specify the number of parameters for function and then use the bind function?

So for example.

```
int f(int a1, int a2);     
int main(){
boost::bind(f, 1);    // error, f takes two arguments
boost::bind(f, 1, 2); // OK
}
```

Comment: How about `int f( int a1, int a2 = 0 );` ?

Comment: Your example has no template parameters...?

Comment: You’ll solve your problem by reading at [boost::bind doc](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bind/bind.html). You need placeholders for not bounded arguments